# overheating problem in samsung np300e 4a

Tags: overheating

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. I'm facing overheating problem. The battery cannot last more than 2 hours and the computer is noisy. My laptop is samsung np300e 4a. Using celeron processor (CPU B800). Can somebody help me?

PS: when I use my windows 7, the temperature is okay, the battery lasts longer, and no noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install TLP this will fix the heating issue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

Once installed, type

```
sudo tlp bat
```

This will make a huge difference in temperature.

Comment: Thank you for your response. TLP is successfully installed, but still, my battery cannot last more than 2 hours.

Comment: @herrysusanto Did the heating issue resolve ??

Comment: I think the heat is reducing, even though it's much much better if I run my computer using windows. As the information, using windows my battery can last for 4 hours, but running it by Ubuntu just 2 hours. If I do updating, it can be lesser.

Comment: Install Hardware Sensor to know the temp changes.
http://www.shodan.in/2014/11/01/display-cpu-and-graphics-temperature-in-ubuntu-14-04/
To improve battery backup you can try updating your graphics driver.

Comment: You know what, I change the driver with invidia 300 something. The temperature is Ok now, I like it. The battery, it can reach 4+ hours. However, it will immediately go down to half of it if I open a program, for example mozzila or libreoffice. Can you help me to find, if any, the save battery setting. Thanks.

Comment: @herrysusanto I have never come across such issues with mozilla or libreoffice. You can still improve battery life, by making changes in "Power Management" settings.

Comment: Hey, no more overheating and battery drain problem. Installing Nvidia and bumblebee is really helpful. I got again the 5+ hours of my battery.